# How to pad images with imagemagick?

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, image-processing

I need to process a set of identically formatted images to get them to conform with my client's website format. I wanted to use ImageMagick's `convert` or `mogrify` instead of `ffmpeg` but I just cant make it work in a clean way. I tried the `-border` and `-extent` options but they behaved sort of inconsistently, so I'm thinking about falling back to the pad filter in `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf "pad=1500:1500:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=white" output.jpg
```

This is just so much more straightforward - you set the canvas size, the location, and the color, and that's it. Is there a similar solution using the ImageMagick tools?

Comment: What have you tried with IM and how did it not work?

Answer (score 2):

I found something that works for me:

```
convert input.jpg -extenet WIDTHxHEIGHT+X+Y -background COLOR output.jpg
```

this allows offsetting much like with the `pad` filter in ffmpeg.
I think what confused me is that the `-bordercolor` option doesn't seem to work on my setup with the `convert` command, while it works fine with `mogrify`. I don't know whether I'm missing something or this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

if you want bottom padding, you could create a transparent image of same size then append that

```
magick image.ext -alpha transparent -write mpr:mem +delete ^ image.ext mpr:mem -append result.jpg
```